# what is value(Type, null) for

Tags: dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

The file [angular.dart/lib/directive/module.dart on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/2a079327092c4f273a4dd0721244364298aab143/lib/directive/module.dart#L37) 
has a lot of lines like

```dart
// class NgDirectiveModule extends Module {
//  NgDirectiveModule() {

    value(NgADirective, null); // <--
```

What is the purpose of this statement.
The second parameter is documented like `The [value] is what actually will be injected.`
Why would I want `null` to be injected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `null` because the directive doesn't exist in the root injector.  Without these statements, attempting to inject an non-existent directive would crash the program with an "unknown type" injector error.

As Angular walks the DOM creating directives, they are made available in child injectors which are created during the DOM walk. e.g.

```html
<div ng-model="foo" my-directive>...</div>
```

In the MyDirective directive, you can inject any other directive:

```dart
class MyDirective {
  MyDirective(NgModel model) {
    if (model.viewValue == "party") dance();
  }
}
```

You can do this for any directive, e.g. `ng-click`, `ng-class`, however most directives don't have useful public interfaces.  But, the `null` value is useful:

```dart
class MyDirective {
  MyDirective(NgRepeatDirective repeat) {
    if (repeat != null) {
       // this element is being repeated
    } else {
       // this element is not being repeated.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I have still quite a few things to learn how DI works in Angular.

Comment: So do we!  Vojta has some awesome work coming: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OGGsf1ZXMs